# How to create dynamic IF statement?

Tags: javascript

I want to make condition of `IF` statement dynamically in javascript

example :

```
function checkNumber(number) {

  var dynamicStatement = 1000000; // IF statement stop 1 million

  if(number <= 1000) {
    return 1000;

  } else if(number <= 2000)
    return 2000;

  } else if(number <= 3000)
    return 3000;

  } else if(number <= 4000)
    return 4000;

  } else if (...) {
    return ...

  } else if (number <= 1000000) {
    return 1000000;

  }

}
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Dynamic in what way? If you just want to get the next thousand, you can easily round it.

Comment: If you can place your code inside a php file you can easily use a php loop to generate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Math.ceil(number/1000)*1000;
```

This will return the value nearest to the multiplier with 1000. For eg. if number is 900 then it will return 1000, if number is 1050 it will return 2000 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function checkNumber(number, limit, step) {
      for(let i = 0; i < limit; i = i+step) {
         if(number <= i) {
           return i;
         }
      }
      throw "Invalid Number";
    }

    checkNumber(75006, 1000000, 1000)
```

Comment: please explain your answer so that other readers can know what the function `checknumber()` does or what is made for.

Answer (score 0):

That answer Bhojendra posted is simple and beautiful, it's probably the one that suits your situation best.

Here's another, using for-loop:

```
function checkNumber(number) {
    var dynamicStatement = 1000000;
    var thousands = dynamicStatement / 1000;
    for(var i = 0; i<thousands; i++){
        if(number <= thousands * i){
            return thousands * i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```